# By+gerunds in formal english

Tags: gerunds

It is encouraged or discouraged the usage of "By+ gerunds" in english formal writing?. If it is not encouraged, how you can explain this situations without using it.

Example: by studying arts kids improve their performance in school

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

We presume there is no such inhibition for using BY+GERUND combination. What's to be looked into is that by doing so the sentence doesn't become wordy or heavy.

- By studying arts, kids improve their performance at school.

It doesn't strike any discordant note and is fine.

- Reading makes a half man, writing makes a full man.

You can make it passive or write it the other way round.

- By reading you are made a half man ...   or
- A half man is made by reading...